# Creating a drop down list where selected item changes size

Tags: jquery, html, css

Take amazon.com for an example, If you click on the filter in their search bar the item selected changes in size whilst the other drop down list items are at a fixed size.

Say I have this html

```
<select>
    <option value="book">book</option>
    <option value="board_game">board game</option>
    <option value="dvd">DVD</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
</select>
```

I would want the item selected, say 'all' to have a smaller width than when 'board_game' was selected. How would I do this in CSS and jquery if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Are you talking about the final width of the option area after it is selected?

Comment: @TimSPQR I'm talking about changing the width of the selected item, i.e the one that you click on to bring down the drop down menu

Comment: Ok, got it. I'm working on a solution by looking at the Amazon code, they put the dropdown in a span. I've got a very preliminary fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/yPtkA/ - I'm going to bed now, but in the morning I'll flog around a bit more - just moving the option selector to the holder div, and styling it...not done yet.

Comment: Looking good, I'll check back in morning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Styling select options seems pretty restricted. My guess would be that Amazon is not using the standard select-option markup. instead they may be using javascript to display a div instead of the option menu. That way they can apply the effect you're attempting.

Im not sure exactly what effect you're after, but ive created a codepen that might be a good starting point for you. It uses jquery to populate a hidden container that gets displayed when you click a dummy select menu.

The html for it looks something like this:

```
<div id="select">
    Item Select
    <option value="book" disabled>book</option>
    <option value="board_game">board game</option>
    <option value="dvd">DVD</option>
    <option value="all" disabled>All</option>
</div>

<div id="options"></div>
```

[Demo is here](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/AqvzB).

Hope this proves to be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I've been flogging on this since you originally posted it, and I learned a lot - thanks.

I've gone over and over the Amazon code, and they have the option in a span. There is lots of styling of the span and option that I can't figure out even with the F12 tools.

But I went back to basics and thought that one of the most common ways to have a width be variable is to use a "span" - so I put the selected text in a span.

Second, it is VERY difficult, if not impossible, to do advanced styling of an option, so the option is only used for the selection process - it is added to the div when needed and removed when finished.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VPqR6/3/).

JS

```
$myoption = "<select class='myselect'><option>selection</option><option>Small</option>                <option>Medium</option><option>Laaaaarge</option><option>Really Looooong</option></select>";

$('.bigdiv').on('click', function(){
    if( $('.bigdiv > .myselect' ).length > 0 )
      { 
       return;
       }
     else
      {
       $('.bigdiv').append($myoption);
       console.log('appended');
       }
});

$( document ).on('change','.myselect', function(){
    console.log('change');
    var myselection = $('.myselect').val();
    console.log('Selection =' + myselection);
    $('.myspan').html( myselection );
    $('.myselect').remove();    
});

$('.remove').on('click', function(){
    $('.myselect').remove();    
});
```

Those Amazon programmers are pretty imaginative and slick. I wish one of them would drop by and give us noobs a hint - without revealing any "secrets" :-)